# how can I use JSP on free domain

Tags: javascript, java

I have written some code in jsp and it works properly in Netbeans because of its local host. Now I'm trying to run this code on a free server and domain and make it unlocal or public which I have it.  How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You should investigate available cloud services

Comment: It is very uncommon for free hosting providers to support JSP.

Comment: @Robert
Hi Robert. Do you know anything about JSP free hosting?

Comment: @ControlAltDel
Appreciate buddy